# Opencart Change Category Links

Tags: php, opencart

I want to edit the parent category link, at the moment it doesn't do anything except display the dropdown menu, anyone know how to edit this?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by ***"edit the parent category link"***?

Comment: When i click on it I want it to open a page not just show the dropdown menu

Answer (score 0):

Just a ***Hint***, the code you are interested in (navigation bar of the categories) is written at the same files of the header:

- Open the file `<OC_ROOT>/catalog/view/theme/<Your_Theme_Folder>/template/common/header.tpl`
- Find the loop that prints categories, in all versions of OC it looks like:
  `<?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>`
- That's it, now you just need to change HTML of parent categories, they are printed inside a code block that looks like:
  `<?php if ($category['children']) { // here } ?>`

Give it a try and I'll be here if you still have a problem